# Using the SciPy DCT function to create a 2D DCT-II

Tags: scipy

I am creating a 2D DCT-II in labview but want to be able to check my outputs are correct. SciPy has a nice DCT function which defaults to DCT-II but is 1D.

I want to make it work for a 2D array. To do this the DCT must be applied to the columns and then the DCT must be again applied to the rows of this outcome.

I'm not sure what function I want to use to do this. I have tried np.rot90 which rotates the numpy array 90 degrees counter clockwise as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.fftpack import dct

a = np.array([[1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0],
[1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0],
[1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0],
[1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0],
[1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0],
[1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0],
[1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0],
[1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0]])

b = dct(np.rot90(dct(a),3))
```

However this outputs the following:

```
array([[ 1152.        ,     0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        ,
            0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        ],
       [ -412.30867345,     0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        ,
            0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        ],
       [    0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        ,
            0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        ],
       [  -43.10110726,     0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        ,
            0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        ],
       [    0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        ,
            0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        ],
       [  -12.85778584,     0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        ,
            0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        ],
       [    0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        ,
            0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        ],
       [   -3.24494866,     0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        ,
            0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        ]])
```

I think that rot90 is not the right function to do what I want to do, perhaps there is a better one?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't think that a rotation is what you want, since it converts rows into columns, but it also messes with the order of the data. Use `np.transpose` instead.

To apply dct first by columns, then by rows, you would do something like:

```
dct(dct(a.T).T)
```

The trailing `.T` is equivalent to `np.transpose`. Note how you need to undo the transposition after you operate on the columns, to get the return aligned by rows again.

I don't think that the order in which you apply the dct, i.e. columns then rows vs. rows then columns, makes any difference, but you could get rows then columns as:

```
dct(dct(a).T).T
```

Answer (score 34):

@Jaime's answer is fine. I'll add that `dct` has an `axis` argument for just this purpose.  First apply it along, say, axis 0, then along axis 1 of the result:

```
In [30]: from scipy.fftpack import dct

In [31]: a.shape
Out[31]: (8, 8)

In [32]: t1 = dct(dct(a, axis=0), axis=1)

In [33]: t2 = dct(dct(a.T).T)

In [34]: np.abs(t1 - t2).max()
Out[34]: 0.0
```

Comment: Handy visual demo: https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee123/sp16/Sections/JPEG_DCT_Demo.html

Answer (score 5):

There is now a multidimensional DCT function (and inverse) as well:

```
>>> from scipy.fft import dctn, idctn
>>> b = dctn(a)
>>> np.allclose(a, idctn(b))
True
```

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.fft.dctn.html

Comment: This is the nicest option. Though it may be smart to assert that a.shape is of the expected form, like a 2D array. As this function will happily do other dimensions too, like 1d,3d etc